# Generate correlated random numbers from binomial distributions

Tags: r, random, correlation

I am trying to find a way to generate correlated random numbers from several binomial distributions.

I know how to do it with normal distributions (using `MASS::mvrnorm`), but I did not find a function applicable to binomial responses.

Comment: You can use package `bindata`, as nicely demo'd here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-July/135575.html . (That link was on the first page returned by a Google search for 'R simulate correlated binomial variable' ...)

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I need binomial not binary data !

Comment: @Arnaud - granted I've not had any sort of caffeine or stimulant this morning, but isn't a binomial distribution a discrete distribution where the only acceptable values are "yes/no", "pass/fail", "TRUE/FALSE", in other words binary? That's what [Wikipedia seems to think too.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @chase - I agree that binary and binomial are based on "yes/no", "1/0" ...etc values, but binary data can take only two
values coded 0 and 1, binomial data is a count of n successes out of x trials (i.e. a proportion of success).But following this idea ... Do binomial variables calculated as the proportion of success in samples of correlated Bernoulli variables are correlated ?

Comment: @Arnaud - I think you may be caught up in the semantics or wording differences. In your binomial example, "n successes out of x trials" means you could be counting the number of red marbles out of a bag. So every red marble gets a value of 1, all other colors have a value of 0. More generally, you can convert your "success" to a value of 1, and failure as a value of 0...or vice versa if that makes more sense for whatever it is you are counting.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the last questions there. Bernoulli trials are simply a single experiment with a binary outcome, "success or failure". When you take a series of *independent* Bernoulli trials with the same probability of success, that is typically referred to as a "binomial distribution".

Comment: I am searching for a way to do it using R ... so I wonder how I can use the rmvbin function to obtain what I want. I need 20 random numbers sampled from 20 different binomial distributions but with a defined correlation between those numbers.

Comment: Point taken. Apparently I *still* hear 'binary' when someone says 'binomial' -- a hard habit to break ;). The solution I just now posted below could probably be greatly speeded up, but it should give you a good start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can generate correlated uniforms using the `copula` package, then use the `qbinom` function to convert those to binomial variables.  Here is one quick example:

```
library(copula)

tmp <- normalCopula( 0.75, dim=2 )
x <- rcopula(tmp, 1000)
x2 <- cbind( qbinom(x[,1], 10, 0.5), qbinom(x[,2], 15, 0.7) )
```

Now `x2` is a matrix with the 2 columns representing 2 binomial variables that are correlated.

Comment: Thanks again Greg ... after your help with optim on the R help, you save me again !

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it doesn't return variables with the desired correlation. (For instance, I calculated sample correlation coefficients for 100 replicates of the above code: the average correlation was 0.724, with just 5 of the correlation coefficients greater than 0.75).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, finding a general closed form solution to generating data (other than normal) with a specified correlation is not simple.  Even working out an exact method for the stated problem would possibly constitute a masters thesis.  But a simple approximation is to simulate like you did, then adjust the value given to the copula, simulate again, etc. until you find a value that is close enough (the original question said that they had to be correlated, not what the correlation coef should be).

Comment: @GregSnow -- Thanks for your response (+1). It's great to get professional confirmation that this isn't a trivial problem, as it sure didn't feel like one, the more I pondered it. (I also like your suggested solution of adjusting the copula to get the desired rho.)

Comment: @Josh O'Brien and Greg Snow - Thanks both for your help and the precision. I made some simulations, and it seems that the higher the number of trials defined in qbinom, the nearer the final correlation is from the correlation defined in normalCopula

Comment: @GregSnow I just tried out your example above and `rcopula()` seems no more to be working. What should we use instead?

Comment: @jaySf, it looks like the copula package has changed.  Use `rCopula(1000, tmp)` instead.

Answer (score 9):

A binomial variable with n trials and probability p of success in each
trial can be viewed as the sum of n Bernoulli trials each also having
probability p of success.

Similarly, you can construct pairs of correlated binomial variates by
summing up pairs of Bernoulli variates having the desired correlation r.

```
require(bindata)

# Parameters of joint distribution
size <- 20
p1 <- 0.5
p2 <- 0.3
rho<- 0.2

# Create one pair of correlated binomial values
trials <- rmvbin(size, c(p1,p2), bincorr=(1-rho)*diag(2)+rho)
colSums(trials)

# A function to create n correlated pairs
rmvBinomial <- function(n, size, p1, p2, rho) {
    X <- replicate(n, {
             colSums(rmvbin(size, c(p1,p2), bincorr=(1-rho)*diag(2)+rho))
         })
    t(X)
}
# Try it out, creating 1000 pairs
X <- rmvBinomial(1000, size=size, p1=p1, p2=p2, rho=rho)
#     cor(X[,1], X[,2])
# [1] 0.1935928  # (In ~8 trials, sample correlations ranged between 0.15 & 0.25)
```

It's important to note that there are *many different joint distributions* that share the desired correlation coefficient. The simulation method in `rmvBinomial()` produces one of them, but whether or not it's the appropriate one will depend on the process that's generating you data.

As noted in [this R-help answer](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/02/10204.html) to a similar question (which then goes on to
explain the idea in more detail) :

> while a bivariate normal (given means and variances) is uniquely defined by the correlation coefficient, this is not the case for a bivariate binomial

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh. I modified your script to allow a larger number of binomial distributions. However, as indicated in http://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-July/135575.html, rho is bounded below and above by some function of the marginal probabilities (the function fail for rho = 0.8). The use of odd ratio seems to be the solution, but ... do you know how to generalize the function proposed that allows converting odds ratio to valid binary correlation for more than 2 distributions ?

Comment: @Josh I've asked a related question, perhaps you might want to take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006881/how-to-generate-a-binomial-vector-of-n-correlated-items

Answer (score 0):

A matrix with correlated binary data can also be iterated by a genetic algorithm, e.g. implemented in the R-package 'RepeatedHighDim' (https://github.com/jkruppa/RepeatedHighDim). The algorithm is described here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010482517303499

```
library(RepeatedHighDim)
X0 <- start_matrix(p = c(0.5, 0.3), k = 1000) # sample size k
R <- diag(2)
R[1,2] = 0.2
R[2,1] = 0.2
X1 <- iter_matrix(X0, R = R, T = 10000, e.min = 0.00001)$Xt
cor(X1)
```

The package implements also two other algorithms:

```
X2 = rmvbinary_EP(n = 1000, R = R, p = c(0.5, 0.3))
X3 = rmvbinary_QA(n = 1000, R = R, p = c(0.5, 0.3))
cor(X2)
cor(X3)
```