# how to simulate correlated binary data with R?

Tags: r, binary, simulation, correlation

Supposing I want 2 vectors of binary data with specified phi coefficients, how could I simulate it with R?

For example, how can I create two vectors like `x` and `y` of specified vector length with the cor efficient of 0.79

```
> x = c(1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1)
> y = c(1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1)
> cor(x,y)
[1] 0.7905694
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10540234/2105757

Comment: @ndoogan -- Well, this is asking for binary data, not binomial, so it's slightly different.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien What is the difference between a binomial model of, for example, a single coin flip, and a random binary model?

Comment: @ndoogan -- Only that certain simulation methods will work for the special case (binary) that won't work so well for the more general (binomial). I'll add an answer showing that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **bindata** package is nice for generating binary data with this and more complicated correlation structures. ([Here's a link to a working paper (warning, pdf)](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/papers/sfb-am/wp13.pdf) that lays out the theory underlying the approach taken by the package authors.)

In your case, assuming that the independent probabilities of x and y are both 0.5:

```
library(bindata)

## Construct a binary correlation matrix
rho <- 0.7905694
m <- matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1), ncol=2)   

## Simulate 10000 x-y pairs, and check that they have the specified
## correlation structure
x <- rmvbin(1e5, margprob = c(0.5, 0.5), bincorr = m) 
cor(x)
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 1.0000000 0.7889613
# [2,] 0.7889613 1.0000000
```

Comment: Seems like a fine answer. But I still don't see why a multivariate binomial model (with trials = 1) is any different. I'll grant that I should have just said Bernoulli model. But that's literally binomial with trials = 1.

Comment: @ndoogan.  It's not any different. Did you notice, though, that the accepted answer in the question you linked to didn't actually generate binomial data with the specified correlation? I just wanted to highlight that for the special case of binary data (or binomial data with trials=1, if you prefer) there **are** nice existing tools.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: I noticed non-negligible deviation of the simulated correlation coefficients and the specified in many runs. Is this the best/closest we can do in simulation?

Comment: @RNA -- The simulated correlations don't appear to me to be systematically biased from 0.7905, so I think that's just expected sampling variation.