# How to draw random multibinomial samples with specified correlation?

Tags: r

Suppose I have three variables with a correlation matrix like this:

```
    y1  y2  y3
y1 1.0 0.2 0.3
y2 0.2 1.0 0.4
y3 0.3 0.4 1.0
```

How could I draw a set of `n` random bernoulli samples of `y1`, `y2`, `y3` under this specified correlation parameters (maybe also with specified probability for each of them)? such like:

```
  y1 y2 y3
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
3  0  0  0
4  0  0  1
5  1  0  0
6  0  1  0
....
n  1  0  0
```

Comment: No, they are different. This one is with specified correlation and that one is just for not iid.

Comment: I've created an answer using code directly from the linked question that solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535235/generate-correlated-random-numbers-from-binomial-distributions-in-r), you could use the `rmvbin` function:

```
# Correlation and marginal probabilities
cor.mat <- matrix(c(1, .2, .3, .2, 1, .4, .3, .4, 1), nrow=3)
marg.prob <- margprob <- c(.1, .2, .3)

# Generate random data
library(bindata)
set.seed(144)
res <- rmvbin(10000, margprob, bincorr=cor.mat)

# Check things are working properly
cor(res)
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 1.0000000 0.1891508 0.2965542
# [2,] 0.1891508 1.0000000 0.3927966
# [3,] 0.2965542 0.3927966 1.0000000
colMeans(res)
# [1] 0.1013 0.1980 0.3029
```

Comment: What is the exact equivalent of this in python ? Anyone ... ?

Comment: @user1301295 If you have a new question you should use the "Ask Question" button instead of asking in the comments.