# How to generate a binomial vector of n correlated items?

Tags: r, random, correlation, bindata

I want to generate a binomial vector based on a number of correlated items each with a defined probability. When I use e. g. `rbinom(1e3, size = 4, prob = c(p.x1, p.x2, p.x3, p.x4))` I'm getting something like `3 3 0 0 2 4 1 0 4 4 0 1 4...`. Now these x_i have adefined probabilities but are not correlated.

Five years ago *Josh O'Brien* contributed a great approach to [generate correlated binomial data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539448/6574038). I think it is close towards my needs, but it is designed for pairs, and I want 1., a single vector and 2., more variables *p*. I already tried to modify the function to produce a greater number of variables but with no success so far and I'm frequently facing

```
Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

which is sent by the imported `bindata` package.

My idea is to define in [*Josh's* function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539448/6574038) four (or better an arbitrary number of) probabilities and *rhos*, something like

```
rmvBinomial3 <- function(n, size, p1, p2, p3, p4, rho) {
  X <- replicate(n, {
    colSums(rmvbin(size, c(p1,p2,p3,p4), bincorr=(1-rho)*diag(4)+rho))
  })
  t(X)
}
```

Sure--more *rhos* are needed and I guess a probabililty matrix should be included somehow as it can be done with the `bindata` package. I do not know how to include it.

```
rho1 <- -0.89; rho2 <- -0.75; rho3 <- -0.62; rho4 <- -0.59
m <- matrix(c(1, rho1, rho2, rho3,
     rho1, 1, rho4, rho2,
     rho2, rho4, 1, rho1,
     rho3, rho2, rho1, 1), ncol = 4) 
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  1.00 -0.89 -0.75 -0.62
# [2,] -0.89  1.00 -0.59 -0.75
# [3,] -0.75 -0.59  1.00 -0.89
# [4,] -0.62 -0.75 -0.89  1.00
```

Unfortunately each matrix, in order to fit the conditions for `bindata` I check with `bindata::check.commonprob(m)`, throws me the same error as above. I also couldn't accomplish to get a matrix created by `bindata::commonprob2sigma()`.

An other drawback for me is the range of Josh's [`rmvBinomial()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539448/6574038), it seems to work only between values for p.X_i= 0.2--0.8 something and I need smaller values e.g. 0.01--0.1, too.

Any help is greatly apprecciated.

***Edit:*** To clarify, the expected outcome is indeed just one single vector `3 3 0 0 2 4 1 0 4 4 0 1 4...` as shown in the beginning, but the items from which it's derived should be correlated to a definable degree (i. e. one of the items could have no correlation at all).