# Copula and simulation of binary and continuous variables

Tags: r, montecarlo, simulationx

I am trying to simulate variables knowing their marginal distribution and their correlation matrix. I know we can use packages like copula but I am not familiar on how to go about it. Can someone help

```
#mean(w1)=0.6, sd(w1)=0.38; w1 is normally distributed
#mean(w2)=0.31; w2 is binary
#mean(w3)=0.226; w3 is binary

cor
           w1         w2         w3
w1  1.0000000 -0.3555066 -0.1986376
w2 -0.3555066  1.0000000  0.1030849
w3 -0.1986376  0.1030849  1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing from the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540234/6455166

```
library(copula)
set.seed(123)
myCop <- normalCopula(param = c(-0.46, -0.27, 0.18), 
                      dim = 3, dispstr = "un")
out <- rCopula(1e5, myCop)
out[, 1] <- qnorm(out[, 1], mean = 0.6, sd = 0.38)
out[, 2] <- qbinom(out[, 2], size = 1, prob = 0.31)
out[, 3] <- qbinom(out[, 3], size = 1, prob = 0.226)

cor(out)
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.0000000 -0.3548863 -0.1943631
# [2,] -0.3548863  1.0000000  0.1037638
# [3,] -0.1943631  0.1037638  1.0000000
colMeans(out)
# [1] 0.5992595 0.3118300 0.2256000
sd(out[, 1])
# [1] 0.3806173
```

**Explanation.**  We draw correlated uniforms, and then convert each vector of uniforms to our desired distributions.  The values for the `param` argument in `normalCopula` were arrived at through trial and error: start with your desired correlations (i.e. `c(-0.3555, -0.1986, 0.103)`), then adjust them until `cor(out)` produces your target correlations.

Comment: Thank you @WeihuangWong. I am not sure how to simulate the get the the bernouilli distribution from the `qbinom` output and likewise the normal distribution from the `qnorm`. Do you have an example, I could use. Thank you

Comment: We are simulating uniform distributions (that's what `rCopula` is doing), and then converting the uniform random variables into Bernoulli and normal (that's what `qbinom` and `qnorm` are doing). It's a two-step process. I'm not sure what additional example you have in mind, beyond what's already in the code above.

Comment: Thank you so much @WeihuangWong. I realized that later when I checked the `qbinom`. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for the timely reply